# How to use tablesample to sample 10 rows from each group in SQL?

Tags: sql

Something like

```
select * over (partition by mygroup tablesample(10) )
```

does not work.

How does one use the given sampling mechanisms to sample from each group? And if this is not possible, what is a way of understanding why it is not achievable in the SQL grammar?

In case someone lands here you can do something like this without tablesample

```
select * from (select *, rank() over (partition by something order by random()) from table) where rank < 10
```

Comment: Tag your specific database platform and explain the actual problem you are trying to solve. I'm not aware of any popular platform that supports this in anything other than a `from` clause.

Comment: @stu Actually found a way using a simple random() and partition usage. I think the tablesample stuff is really not that helpful and distracts from more basic solutions. TABLESAMPLE or SAMPLE are pretty common APIs I just don't think they are deeply embedded or something. Probably why not much comes up in searches.